# glReadPixel returns 0 in android 1.6

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am using min3d for importing 3D model in *.obj format to android 1.6. However, I need to detect which face I am touching. So I intend to use color picking using the following code.

```
FloatBuffer pixel = FloatBuffer.allocate(4);
                IntBuffer viewport = IntBuffer.allocate(4);
                gl.glGetIntegerv(GL11.GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);
                gl.glFlush();
                viewport.position(0);
                gl.glReadPixels((int) x, (int) (viewport.get(3) - y), 1, 1,
                        GL10.GL_RGBA, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixel);

                Log.d("Pixel Values:", pixel.get(0) + " " + pixel.get(1) + " "
                        + pixel.get(2) + " " + pixel.get(3));
```

where x and y are co-ordinates received from onTouch listener. When this code is executed I always get 0 0 0 0 in logs. How to solve this ?

Comment: Are you sure the pixel isn't actually black (0,0,0,0)?

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply but no. Its blue and background is white.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no user of Android, but you're passing a FloatBuffer to glReadPixels and type is GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, maybe you want a ByteBuffer or switch type to GL_FLOAT.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply but it doesn't work. Changing to GL_FLOAT, returns 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0

Comment: Is your call generating any GL errors? You can check that with glGetError()

Comment: Yes. I am getting Error code : 2597872. Don't know what it means though.

Comment: Mmm, that's not a valid GL error code. Are you sure you got it from glGetError()? Also be sure that glReadPixels is indeed the faulty call by putting glGetError() before and after the call.

Comment: I tried from the beginning of the code and called glGetError() in most of places. I had no issues till onSurfaceChanged function. However, in the beginning of onDrawFrame function of GLSurfaceView.Renderer interface I am getting 1280, invalid enum error. How to solve this ?

Comment: Hello, is it broken in android? Can you find any solution for this?